# How can I make a java program that takes an input of words, finds certain words, replaces them and then prints out everything again?

Tags: java

I am not sure what to do, I have found all this online and I am trying to change it to do what I explained above but I am stuck. Basically what I want to do is copy and paste an essay into the code somewhere, the have it look through the essay for any words i tell it to look for, and if it finds them then to replace it with the word or words I want it to.

```
/**
     * 

    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Main {
        public static String[] wordList(String line){
            return line.split(" ");
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {    
            String words = "test words tesing";
            String[] arr = wordList(words);
            for(words i=0; i<words.length; i++)
            for (String s: arr)
                System.out.println(s);
        }

    }

    */

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Main {

        public static void main ( String args[] ){
            String[] sEnterWord = getSortedWordArr();
            showWordlist(sEnterWord);
            String sWordToChange = getInputFromKeyboard("Which word would you like to change? ");
            System.out.println("You have chosen to change the word : " + sWordToChange);
            changeWordInArray(sWordToChange, sEnterWord);
            Arrays.sort(sEnterWord);
            showWordlist(sEnterWord);
        }

        private static String[] getSortedWordArr(){
            String line = getInputFromKeyboard("How many words are you going to enter? ");
            int length = Integer.valueOf(line);

            String[] sEnterWord = new String[length];

            for(int nCtr = 0; nCtr < length; nCtr++){
                sEnterWord[nCtr] = getInputFromKeyboard("Enter word " + (nCtr+1) + ":");
            }

            Arrays.sort(sEnterWord);

            return sEnterWord;
        }

        private static String getInputFromKeyboard(String prompt){
            System.out.print(prompt);
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = s.nextLine();

            return input;
        }

        private static void showWordlist(String[] words){
            System.out.println("Your words are: ");
            for (String w : words){
                System.out.println(w);
            }
        }

        private static void changeWordInArray(String word, String[] array){
            String newWord = getInputFromKeyboard("Enter the new word: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                if (array[i].equals(word)){
                    array[i] = newWord;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Arrays.sort(array);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not the usual homework question. You’re apparently writing a program to copy homework and need help perfecting it?

Comment: Break it down step by step and build it from there, rather than copying something you found online.

Answer (score 0):

To read from the keyboard use

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);

String cadena = br.readLine();
```

And all the words you introduced form the keyboard will be in "cadena".
To separte all the words you introduced you could use the method split from String.class.

```
String[] words = cadena.split(" ");
```

To find a specific word you could use a method and the code would be in your method would be:

```
String yourWord = "";
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    if(words[i].equals("your word"))
    {
        yourWord = words[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

To replece a word use the method replce(theWord, "the replacement")

You can prints all the words using a loop for with System.out.println(yourWord);